# Load an UIView or a UITableView based on one variable

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview

My app has a "favorites" tab. Inside, of course, there are the items (in a UITableView)  that the user has set to "favorite".

My problem is this: when, at the starts, the user has no favorites, i want to show an UIView (with an UIButton "add favorite") and not the UITableView...

is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it will be a simple conditional in your code, preferably within the `viewWillAppear:` method. Something like the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.hasFavorites) {
        // add UITableView as a subview
    } else {
        // add UIButton as a subview
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks and... how can i add the subview? [self addsubview:my_view] doesn't works...

Comment: This is assuming neither of the views have been added yet, but either set up in code or through IB and connected. Yes, `[self addSubview:aView]` is the method you want to use.

Comment: in my .h file i've insered `IBOutlet UIView *myview` and setted the property. Then in .m '@synthesize myview` and finnaly in IB created an UIView and connected to "myview" in the file's owner.  Now in my .m file if i write `[self addSubview:myview` xcode tell me "may not respond to -addSubview"

Comment: Sorry, is you are calling it from the view controller, it is `[self.view addSubview:myview];`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. I'm assuming you have the user's favorite store in some kind of Array. So simply:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //Reload the array here.
    [self loadFavoriteArray];

    if (_favoriteArray == nil || [_favoriteArray count] < 1) {
        [_favoriteTableView setHidden:YES];
        [_noFavoriteView setHidden:NO];
    }
    else {
        [_favoriteTableView setHidden:NO];
        [_noFavoriteView setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your view set up - UIViewController or UITableViewController? If I understand your question correctly, I think you have a couple options.

1) You could set the tableHeaderView. This would allow you to have a button above the table which could be populated with a single cell that reads 'No Favorites'...or something like that.  Would allow you to remove the button if they have a favorite listed, or you could even leave it there for good as a quick way to add additional favorites

2) Assuming your using a UIViewController (and subsequently adding your UITableView), and not UITableViewController, you could simply just not add the UITableView subview if they don't have any favorites.

Hope that helps...